# How to detect if a table contains a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple tables need to be nested with divs

Like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>

   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>EEE</td>
     <td>EEE</td>
    </tr>
   </table>

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then, I get each table with the code below:

var isert = inn.getElementsByTagName("table");

```
for(var i = 0 ;i<isert.length;i++)
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var _t = isert[i];
    var parent = _t.parentNode;
    div.className = "extra";
    parent.replaceChild(div, _t);
    div.appendChild(_t);
    } 
}
```

So the table becomes:

```
<div class="extra">
<table>
     <tr>
      <td>

      <div class="extra">
       <table>
        <tr>
         <td>EEE</td>
         <td>EEE</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </div>

      </td>
     </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

However, after I adding css styles to class "extra", they are overlapped. So what I need is a method like below to detect whether this table contains a table inside.

```
if( ! 'table' contains 'table'){
...adding the div...
}
```

I hope this could be solve by pure JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of themes you're working with, but you would conceivably be able to solve this with pure CSS

```
table { some theme style; }
table table { revert to default style; }
```

**EDIT**

From what I understand after your update, you want to turn the following code int something that doesn't rely on jQuery, correct?

```
var curr = $(this); 
if(!curr.has('table').length) {
```

`getElementsByTagName` is available on all tag nodes and will only yield child elements, so you could do that check as follows:

```
if(!curr.getElementsByTagName('table').length) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made some adjustment to my question so that it may be more clear. CSS should not be changed, and I have to work with JavaScript.